# PHP : converting an UCS-2 LE BOM string to UTF-8 stops working once i write the string to a file

Tags: php, utf-8, charset

I am currently having a hard time trying to do the simplest thing :

I have a UCS-2 LE BOM encoded file that I am converting to UTF-8.
Here is what Notepad++ says about the encoding :
[image: notepad plus plus screenshot]

My converting routine is simple :

1. I am opening the input file and creating an output file.
2. I am parsing the input file and converting everyline on-the-go to the UTF-8 format
3. Once the converting is done, I remove the input file
4. Once the input file is removed, I rename my output file to the name of the input file

Here is the code that does it :

```
public function convertCsvToUtf8(string $absolutePathToFile) : string {
    $dotPosition = strrpos($absolutePathToFile, ".");
    $absolutePathToNewFile = substr($absolutePathToFile, 0, $dotPosition)."-utf8.csv";

    $res_input_file = fopen($absolutePathToFile, "r");
    $res_output_file = fopen($absolutePathToNewFile, "w+");
    while($input_string = fgets($res_input_file)){
        $inputEncoding = mb_detect_encoding($input_string, mb_list_encodings(), true);
        $output_string = iconv($inputEncoding, 'UTF-8', $input_string);
        fputs($res_output_file, ($output_string));
    }
    fclose($res_input_file);
    fclose($res_output_file);
    unlink($absolutePathToFile);
    rename($absolutePathToNewFile, $absolutePathToFile);
    return $absolutePathToFile;
}
```

Here you can see an example of an execution :
[image: xdebug screenshot]

So... everything seems to be okay at a first glance (expect the fact that the "°" is replaced by a weird character); but when I open the output file with Notepad++, here is a sample what I see :
[image]

I have no idea what is going on here.
Any help would be awesome !
Feel free to ask for more details !
Thanks in advance,

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding` is not reliable. If you *know* the encoding of the source file, type that explicitly for the input encoding parameter. You have no idea what `mb_detect_encoding` detects as encoding here. And it in fact detects Latin-1, as your debugger shows.

Comment: There's `ÿþ` at the start of what your screenshot shows, so I guess that means N++ did _not_ recognized this as a UTF-16 (LE) BOM. Could it be that the original UTF-8 BOM is still contained _before_ that, at the very beginning of the file? Use a hex editor to check. (Or check what encoding N++ actually detected first.)

Comment: it turns out that i had to force encoding to utf8 from the input encoding i knew AND that it still didn't work when converting line by line so I had to convert the whole file's content at once and get it with file_get_contents. too bad for my performances.